# Convert Processing In a Loop updating many lists to CompletableFuture

Tags: java-8, completable-future

I have a List of Strings and for each item in the list ( which  is basically a filename ), I have to do some processing.  I have the sequential process working, but I would like to convert this to CompleatableFuture, where I have to update many lists.  How can I go about it?

This is my original code

```
Path fileLocation = findLocationForFiles(fileDTSuffix);
Map<String, Map<String, String>> csvMap = getCsvToMap("filename", fileLocation);
List<String> filesMissingCSV = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> expiredAssets = new ArrayList<>();

int filesUploaded = 0;
int filesProcessed = 0;
//TODO : Convert below to use CompletableFuture to perform the actions in thread

for (String fileName : filesToProcessList) {
    if(filesProcessed > 100){
        System.out.println("Processed 100 files - calling cleanupTempDir ..... ");
        cleanupTempDir(fileLocation);
        filesProcessed = 0;
    }
    Path path = Paths.get(fileName);

    File file = new File(fileName);
    String baseFileName = file.getName();
    String translatedNameFromVW = translateFilenameFromVW(baseFileName);
    String translatedNameFromVWSansConfig = translateFilenameFromVWSansConfig(baseFileName);
    String translatedNameToVW = translateFilenameToVW(baseFileName);
    boolean isFilenameEqFromVW = baseFileName.equalsIgnoreCase(translatedNameFromVW);
    boolean isFilenameEqToVW = baseFileName.equalsIgnoreCase(translatedNameToVW);
    Map<String, String> csvFileInfo = getCSVMapAttributes(csvMap, baseFileName, translatedNameFromVW, translatedNameFromVWSansConfig, translatedNameToVW);

    if (null == csvFileInfo) {
        filesMissingCSV.add(fileName + " | " + file.getName());
    } else {
        if (!isAssetExpired(csvFileInfo)) {
            AssetMaster am = generateJSON(fileName, csvFileInfo);
            addToCassandra(path, am, translatedNameToVW);
            printJson(am, fileLocation);
            filesUploaded++;
            filesProcessed++;
        } else {
            expiredAssets.add(fileName + " | " + file.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to convert it to use CompletableFutures as below

```
List<CompletableFuture> asyncThreadsList = new ArrayList();

for (String fileName : filesToProcessList) {
    asyncThreadsList.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try {
            processEachFile(csvMap, fileName, fileLocation);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UploadThreaded.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }));
}
CompletableFuture.allOf(asyncThreadsList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]))
   .thenRunAsync(() -> System.out.println("Ended doing things"));
```

And my definition of `processEachFile(csvMap, fileName, fileLocation)` is as below

```
private static CompletableFuture<Void> processEachFile(Map<String, Map<String, String>> csvMap, String fileName, Path fileLocation) throws IOException {

    if (filesProcessed > 100) {
        System.out.println("Processed 100 files - calling cleanupTempDir ..... ");
        cleanupTempDir(fileLocation);
        filesProcessed = 0;
    }
    Path path = Paths.get(fileName);

    File file = new File(fileName);
    String baseFileName = file.getName();
    String translatedNameFromVW = translateFilenameFromVW(baseFileName);
    String translatedNameFromVWSansConfig = translateFilenameFromVWSansConfig(baseFileName);
    String translatedNameToVW = translateFilenameToVW(baseFileName);
    boolean isFilenameEqFromVW = baseFileName.equalsIgnoreCase(translatedNameFromVW);
    boolean isFilenameEqToVW = baseFileName.equalsIgnoreCase(translatedNameToVW);
    Map<String, String> csvFileInfo = getCSVMapAttributes(csvMap, baseFileName, translatedNameFromVW, translatedNameFromVWSansConfig, translatedNameToVW);

    if (null == csvFileInfo) {
        filesMissingCSV.add(fileName + " | " + file.getName());
    } else {
        if (!isAssetExpired(csvFileInfo)) {
            AssetMaster am = generateJSON(fileName, csvFileInfo);
            addToCassandra(path, am, translatedNameToVW);
            printJson(am, fileLocation);
            filesUploaded++;
            filesProcessed++;
        } else {
            expiredAssets.add(fileName + " | " + file.getName());
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

My problem is I need to merge these lists from each run : `filesMissingCSV`, `expiredAssets` and also update the counts `filesUploaded` and `filesProcessed` from each run to get the final values.   And I am having difficulty in figuring out how should that be achieved.

Is it possible to do it and how should that be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@adbdkb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/913749/adbdkb) commented *I actually have an outer loop for this for the Directories and this loop is for files in each directory. Using the same mechanism that you have shown here, can I create the CompletableFutures list for the outer loop as well?*

so I decided to provide a simple solution just covers main OP's problems.

first I created a class to process result for each file.

```
class ProcessDetail {
  private int fileUploaded;
  private int fileProcessed;
  private List<String> expireFile = new ArrayList<>();
  private List<String> missingFile = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

also there are some methods to simplify the task.
first method is `processEachDir`. I just pass a list of string as an argument that represent files of directory. this method returns `List<CompletableFuture<ProcessDetail>>`.

```
private static List<CompletableFuture<ProcessDetail>> processEachDir(List<String> dir) {
    System.out.println(dir + " time: " + LocalDateTime.now());
    sleep(1);
    return dir.stream()
            .map(fileName -> processEachFile(fileName))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

second method is `processEachFile` that get a string parameter that represent file name. 
this method returns `CompletableFuture<ProcessDetail>`

```
private static CompletableFuture<ProcessDetail> processEachFile(String fileName) {
    System.out.println(fileName + " time: " + LocalDateTime.now());

    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        ProcessDetail processDetail = new ProcessDetail();
        if (csvFileInfo()) {
            processDetail.getMissingFile().add(fileName);
        } else if (!isAssetExpired()) {
            processDetail.setFileProcessed(1);
            processDetail.setFileUploaded(1);
        } else {
            processDetail.getExpireFile().add(fileName);
        }
        return processDetail;
    });
}
```

now time to complete the task: 
for each directory bellow code create list of `CompletableFuture<ProcessDetail>` and process files and other stuffs. and put its result into map with directory name as key. `processDetails.put(dir.getKey(), result);`

```
directories.entrySet().forEach(dir -> {
        List<CompletableFuture<ProcessDetail>> list = processEachDir(dir.getValue());
        CompletableFuture.allOf(list.toArray(new CompletableFuture<?>[0]))
                .thenAccept(nothing -> {
                    ProcessDetail result = list.stream()
                            .map(CompletableFuture::join).reduce(new ProcessDetail(), merge);
                    processDetails.put(dir.getKey(), result);

                });
});
```

***[DEMO](https://rextester.com/IOZIN21537)***

Comment: Thanks, @Hadi J.  You not only answered my original and added question, you helped with putting all that together.  The code will help me understand how to use CompletableFuture even better.